# removing en extension from a file in a loop

Tags: php, html

im trying to remove the file extension from each file name in a loop so ball.jpg can be echoed as ball, but it isnt working for me

I have this code

```
$files = array();
foreach($src_files as $file)
{  
    $ext = strrchr($file, '.');
if(in_array($ext, $extensions)) 
{      
   array_push( $files, $file);
   $thumb = $src_folder.'/'.$file;
    $fileName = basename($file);
    $place = preg_replace("/\.[^.]+$/", "", $fileName); 
}      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$src_files = array('/tmp/path/file1.txt', '/tmp/path/file2.txt.php', '/tmp/not.ext');
$extensions = array('.txt', '.php');

$files = array();
foreach ($src_files as $file)
{  
    $ext = strrchr($file, '.');
    var_dump($ext);
    if (in_array($ext, $extensions)) 
    {      
        array_push($files, $file);
        //$thumb = $src_folder.'/'.$file; 
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($file);
        $fileName = $pathInfo['basename'];
        $place = $pathInfo['filename'];
        var_dump($pathInfo);
    } 
}
```

If you just want the filename, without extension, use `pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);`. See [here](https://secure.php.net/pathinfo) for more information.

If you don't want to use `pathinfo()`, you can also use string manipulation techniques:

```
$place = substr($fileName, 0 , (strrpos($fileName, ".")));
```

`strrpos()` is like `strpos()`, but searches for a character starting from the end of the string and working backwards.